# Does HCl evaporate at room temperature?

Tags: acid-base

So my question is...lets say that somebody pours hcl (30%) in the toilet and on bathroom floor.Does the acid evaporate after a while it is it possible that it's still present after like month?
Thank you so much for any answer.

Comment: Yes it does evaporate. There will be no trace of it after a month, even if there were no cleaning (but then again, in that case acid is not your biggest problem).

Answer (score 1):

I would be less concerned with evaporation rate than with the possibility of reaction between the acid and the material on the floor.  If you cannot avoid acid getting on the floor, wipe it up immediately and rinse thoroughly down the drain.  Protective gloves, if you have them, would be good.